Increate a number by one
I have a bunch of DIVs sharing the same class name.  I need to apply z-index for each div, dynamically.  z-index: 1 should be for a first div, z-index: 2 for a second div and so on, but somehow my script doesn't work as expected!
$(".siblingsDiv").each(function() {
    for( var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    $(this).css('z-index', i)
  }
}) 

i<9 is just a demo for this sample.  But in reality I don't know how many DIVs will get in, so how to drive on this part?
Please show me where is wrong.  Thanks


$(".siblingsDiv").each(function() {
    for( var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    $(this).css('z-index', i)
  }
})
.siblingsDiv {
  background: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="siblingsDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="siblingsDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="siblingsDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="siblingsDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="siblingsDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>




"i<9 is just a demo for this sample." but why is there even a loop? $(".siblingsDiv").each() is the code that goes through each div. Then for each div you loop 0-8. Therefore, you set the z-index nine times on each div.

The issue with your script is that you're using a for loop inside the each method. This causes each .siblingsDiv element to loop 9 times, overwriting the z-index value. Instead, you should use the index provided by the .each() method itself to apply the correct z-index dynamically.
After fixing, your code should look like this:
$(".siblingsDiv").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('z-index', index + 1); // index starts from 0, so we add 1
});


Thank you very much for pointing out my code's issue and thanks for your correction!
